# Vertical scroll in div differences between Firefox and Chrome

Tags: javascript, css, browser, fullcalendar, compatibility

I'm having some trouble understanding the way browsers are interpreting vertical scrolling inside a div that houses the fullCalendar js calendar.

In Firefox I can inspect the element and I see this:

```
<div class="fc-agenda-body" style="position: relative; z-index: 2; overflow: auto; height: 572px; width: 706px;">
```

In Chrome I inspect the same element and I see this:

```
<div class="fc-agenda-body" style="position: relative; z-index: 2; width: 705px; overflow: hidden; height: 570px; ">
```

So - my question is how do I stop Chrome (and Safari) changing overflow: auto; to overflow: hidden?

Any advice appreciated.

Thanks!

Simon

Comment: It shouldn't ever change it if you specify it.

Comment: overflow-x and overflow-y override overflow:, perhaps setting the more specific properties would do it.